# using android sensor to get Direction when moving android device

Tags: android, sensors

i'm going to make an app that will get **Direction** when moving android device **on ground** from

- left to right
- top to bottom
- right to left
- bottom to top

at first i need to reset **x** and **y** position to **0**
then by moving android device , get the values !

i'm new in android and i don't know is there any sensor for it or not .
so i didn't try any code to share it :|

is it possible ? any idea ?
is that any sensor that may help me ?

> ***" i have to use android device on ground and i can't pick up the phone "***

Answer (score 1):

Yea there is a sensor event listener in android using this you can get your requirements done. [This](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html) is the official documentation. [This](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSensor/article.html) sample tutorial will help you to start.